# Weightage Search in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, sphinx

I would like to search in MySQL like I type "engineer" then it should also return results Like "Engine" or "Eng" Or "Engineers".
Is it possible using MySQL or is there any other tool which can do this?

Answer (score 0):

This partly can be covered by using the stemmed version of the search term.

This is currently not supported, but might be integrated in a future version of MySQL server. Task [WL#2423](http://MySQL.https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2423)

A MySQL plugin like [mnoGoSearch](http://www.mnogosearch.org/doc/msearch-udmstemmer.html) can be used alternatively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use MySQL LIKE operator in reverse way.
Here columnName is the name of the column where you want to search

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE ('engineer' LIKE CONCAT(columnName,'%')) OR ('engineer' LIKE CONCAT(LOWER(columnName),'%'));
```

Here if you do not want to ignore CASE , you can use the query upto OR. If you want to type input as ENGINEER, you can use UPPER same as like LOWER.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with SPhinx (you already tagged this question for sphinx)

the morphology processor includes a stemmer, 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-morphology

Would allow `engineer` to match `engineers` etc.

It wouldnt directly cope with `engineer` matching `eng` thats more complicated as would some way of finding valid 'short' versions. Could use wordforms, to create a list of them, eg `eng > engineer`. Not sure a general solution is possible as not all 'short forms' would be approate, eg if serach 'bodybuilder', matching 'body' probably wouldnt work, even though start the same very different meanings.